# Drop non SSL packets on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ssl, iptables, load-balancing

I would like to filter out all non-SSL based traffic for a specific port (443).

Is there a way to do this with `iptables`, or another Linux application?

Comment: May I ask why you would do that? Layer 7 filtering is not the easiest thing in the world

Comment: There is a load balancer (AWS ELB) in front of the servers, that sends both an SSL and non-SSL health check. The non-SSL "ping" is causing a lot of chaff in the logs, and is impacting the performance of the application. It is not possible to disable the non-SSL ping, hence why I wish to filter it out entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure if you get a better performance by this. Filtering at that level is quite complex and can be more CPU heavy. Can't you configure your application to just ignore http traffic on this port?

Comment: Afraid not, it's bound to the port and can accept any traffic

Comment: As wireshark (http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) doesn't support capture filtering SSL, I assume it's not a trivial task iptables can do.
Try using HTTP router/reverse proxy (e.g. Nginx, or HAproxy)

Answer (score 2):

If the logs are the problem, you might want to filter the request from the logs. If you're using Apache, you can achieve this by adding lines like these to your virtual host config:

```
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/status\.php$" dontlog
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!dontlog
```